# PowerShell date parsing not working in AD query

Tags: powershell, date, datetime, parsing, active-directory

I am trying to get a list of AD users whose account expired for more than 6 months.

Here is my code :

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $False} -Properties employeeID,sn,givenName,LastLogonDate | Where-Object {[STRING]$_.LastLogonDate -ne "" -and (Get-Date) -gt ([datetime]::parseexact([STRING]$_.LastLogonDate, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", $null)).AddMonths(6)} | select employeeID,sn,givenName,sAMAccountName,LastLogonDate | Sort-Object -Property sn | Export-Csv -Path $filename
```

I get the error :
`The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in the System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar`

I also tried (Get-Culture) in parseexact. Doesn't work either.

While when simply executing something like `[datetime]::parseexact("21/05/2015 16:14:37", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", $null)`
it works as expected.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Property `LastLogonDate` is already a `[DateTime]` object. This is a PowerShell convenience property where LDAP attribute `lastLogonTimeStamp` has been converted to local time for you. You can use `.AddMonths(6)` directly on the property.

Comment: Well that makes sense... Thanks a lot. Just figured out that I needed to use $_. to access LastLogonDate... Have a great day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve your query by adding `LastLogonDate` to the [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)) and remove `Where-Object`:

```
$limit = [datetime]::Now.AddMonths(-6).Date
$params = @{
    Filter = "LastLogonDate -lt '$limit' -and Enabled -eq '$false'"
    Properties = 'LastLogonDate', 'sn', 'EmployeeID'
}

Get-ADUser @params | Sort-Object sn | Export-Csv ....
```

Comment: @Theo probably a good idea hehe, also `[datetime]::Today.AddMonths(...)` should be the same. Thanks